# ImageButton Click event not triggering

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton

I searched but whatever I found didn't work. I have a list that needs to be generated based on a few inputs. Once all have been added, you press a button and it generates a list of pdfs with a few extra fields for description in a Table. Each row has an image button which you click to generate and open the pdf in the browser. The problem is, when clicking, the page seems to just refresh and erases the list, instead of running the function I passed to generate the pdf. IOW, the **btn_exPDF_Click** function is not called. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the backend:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        String id_insp_max = "";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["stelar_conexiune"].ToString();
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd_id_insp = new SqlCommand();
        cmd_id_insp.Connection = conn;

        cmd_id_insp.CommandText = *SQL commands based on input*

        SqlDataReader rd_id_insp = cmd_id_insp.ExecuteReader();

        if(rd_id_insp.HasRows)
        {
            while(rd_id_insp.Read())
            {
                id_insp_max = rd_id_insp[rd_id_insp.GetOrdinal("ID_INSP")].ToString();

                TableRow row = new TableRow();

                TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
                TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
                TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();

                cell1.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                cell2.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                cell3.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;

                cell2.Text = rd_id_insp[rd_id_insp.GetOrdinal("DataInspectie")].ToString();
                cell3.Text = rd_id_insp[rd_id_insp.GetOrdinal("IDPOD")].ToString();


                ImageButton img_select_pdf = new ImageButton();
                img_select_pdf.ImageUrl = "/Content/images/exp_pdf_mini.png";

                img_select_pdf.ID = id_insp_max;

                img_select_pdf.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(btn_exPDF_Click);

                Controls.Add(img_select_pdf);

                cell1.Controls.Add(img_select_pdf);

                row.Cells.Add(cell1);
                row.Cells.Add(cell2);
                row.Cells.Add(cell3);

                tbl_inspectii.Rows.Add(row);

                tbl_inspectii.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            }
        }
        rd_id_insp.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }

    protected void btn_exPDF_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
    //Code to generate PDF
    }
```

Comment: Dynamic contents need to be recreated on (or before) Page_Load

Comment: Not related to your problem: I would change that `if(reader.HasRows)` ... `while(reader.Read())` into a more simple `if(reader.Read())`

Comment: All controls and every other object are disposed at the end of the page's lifecycle. That means you have to re-create them on postback in Page_Init or Page_Load. https://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_